# View layout conflicts when switching to landscape mode

Tags: iphone, ios, view, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a problem with my iOS application ...

This is what it looks like in portrait mode, pretty normal, nothing bad I could say. 
[image]

This is what it looks like in landscape mode.

[image]

The view beneath the segmented control overgrows, covering the segmented control.

I tried to change the settings in the size inspector and the best thing I could do is this:
[image]

Still not what I wanted (now white stripe beneath the segmented control covers the view, and I still don't know where it came from).

I would really appreciate if someone could help me make the landscape view similar to the portrait one, regarding the segmented control - > view thing.

Comment: Check that your autosize spring/strut settings look correct. (Either in interface builder, or in code, if you create your UI using code.)
If you're not familiar with these, have a look at http://is.gd/W1NKCD (search for the text 'autosize').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will have to use autosizing ... 
tutorial for autosizing can be found here :
http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-beginner-tutorials/how-to-use-autorotation-and-autosizing-in-iphone/

Comment: yeah... i've tried what is there but there is no change , the display is still the same..